# MySQL: Two counts in a statement

Tags: mysql, count

I run a Bridal Shop. I have made a table, where we insert all the dresses which are  tried on by the brides. I have the fields, branch, model, date and ordered. If a dress will be ordered, then ordered will be set to 1. I have also the field "status" which will be set to 2 if the dress will be deleted from this table.

I have this statement to show year, month, branch, model and the quantity each model has been tried on:

```
SELECT count(*) as Anzahl, MONTHNAME( date ) AS Monat, YEAR( date ) AS Jahr, 
branch as Branch FROM wccrm_anprobe where status = 1 GROUP BY MONTHNAME(date), 
YEAR(date), branch ORDER BY date,branch ASC
```

What can I do to achieve the following: I want to count the field "ordered" and put it to my select? I want to see, how many dresses have been sold per year, month and branch.

I tried:

```
SELECT count(*) as Anzahl, MONTHNAME( date ) AS Monat, YEAR( date ) AS Jahr, 
branch as Branch, ordered as Ordered FROM wccrm_anprobe where status = 1 GROUP 
BY MONTHNAME(date), 
YEAR(date), branch, ordered ORDER BY date,branch ASC
```

but I do not get the correct results as I think the ordered field will displayed once - it will not be count.

So for example, last month I sold 6 dresses, but the statement above just shows 3 dresses.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Best Regards,

Stefan

Comment: Table Schema,Sample data and expected output will help.

Comment: You don't want to do a SUM() instead of a COUNT()?  `SELECT MONTHNAME( date ) AS Monat, YEAR( date ) AS Jahr, 
branch as Branch, SUM(ordered) as Ordered FROM wccrm_anprobe where status = 1 GROUP 
BY MONTHNAME(date), 
YEAR(date), branch, ordered ORDER BY date,branch ASC`

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use *conditional aggregation*, in your case it should look something like this:

```
COUNT(CASE `ordered` WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS numberOrdered
```

COUNT, like most aggregate functions, ignores NULL values. Alternatively, you could use SUM

```
SUM(CASE `ordered` WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numberOrdered
```